# How to copy files more than once into the same folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy

Say I have a file, `file.txt` and I want to copy it into this folder, `d:/Folder1`, except I need it more than once. When I go CTRL+C the file, it goes `file - Copy.txt` but when I try to use `copy` in batch, it says I cannot overwrite the file.

How do I make it is it copies more than once into that folder?

Comment: I think you need to give different names for each file

Comment: I think this is an _XY problem_. You have one problem, and you're trying to solve it by making copies of the same file in a directory, which is where you get stuck. But it would be much more straightforward if you told us what the original problem was. Perhaps there are better solutions than to create redundant files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch file will make 100 copies starting at `file1.txt` to `file100.txt`

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,100) do copy /b "c:\folder\data\file.txt" "d:\folder1\file%%a.txt"
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works? I want to learn how to use this in other instances.

Comment: `@echo off & for /L %%a in (1,1,100) do echo "%%a"` <--- Execute this in a batch file.  You will see what the FOR /L command does, then type `for /?` and you can read the help on the different for command types but in particular the `for /L`.  Also change the middle `,1,` to `,10,` and rerun it, to see the difference.  The rest of the command is a copy command.